# Imported subclasses not recognised

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to use the CVCalendar framework but Xcode doesn't seem to recognise the files, so perhaps I am importing them wrong.

In Storyboard however I can change a views class to any of the CVCalendar subclasses, it's just in my view controller that the files aren't recognised and when linking my storyboard views I'm getting undeclared type errors.

The instructions were to simple copy the folder containing all of the swift files into my project which I did and copied if required.

Did I miss something?

Comment: `import CVCalendar` in source files where you are using it

Comment: @JakubVano Yeah I tried that but it gives - No Such Module 'CVCalendar'

Comment: I have the exact same problem as you have, could you fix it? It would help me a lot.

Comment: @Fustigador I wasn't able to solve it I'm afraid

Comment: I ended up just copy+paste the files of CVCalendar in my project...that way worked.